# hyperlink column in data grid c#

Tags: c#, datagrid

i am using data set from an access database to populate my data grid. One of the column in the table of database is an hyperlink, i cant get to make it appear as an hyper link in the data grid

```
  OleDbDataAdapter da=new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from UniversityData",connection ) ;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dgvUniversity.ItemsSource = dt.AsDataView ();
```

this is how i populate my data grid, can someone please tell me how to make it appear as an hyper link

Comment: you try to grid view option

Comment: You need to add `DataGridViewLinkColumn` into your datagridview and handle it click on `CellContentClick` event